# Android 4.2.2 device can't connect to server

Tags: android, android-async-http

I am developing an Android app. The http requests are working fine with most devices, but a user with an Android 4.2.2 device can't connect to the server. What goes wrong?

Comment: Are you using https?

Comment: needs more code

Comment: Can you post a code snippet or verbose device log? and what type of network connection are you running the 4.2.2 device on?

Comment: As the URL I connect with begins with https I guess I am using it.

Comment: without more info we can only speculate: connection: wlan? umts? firewall? dns-server? local internet address (i.e. 192.168....) not reachable from internet, .....Can the android-4.2.2 internet browser reach the page?